# How to add Default.aspx as default document

Tags: asp.net, iis-10

I have a new Windows Server 2016 with IIS 10.0.

I have a ASP.NET 4.6.2 application with a Default.aspx file.

When I point my browser to the application I get this error:

```
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden

The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.
```

I suspect that IIS is not configured for ASP.NET because the `Default Document` does not include `Default.aspx`.

I have .Net Framework 4.6.2 as evidenced that I get an error message that is is already installed when I try to install it again.

The application pool lists `CLR 4.0`, but does not allow me to change it to 4.6.2.

What do I try to get this configured to load my Default.aspx.

When I google I stumble on things that tell me to run stuff from the command line.  I am perfectly comfortable running things from the command line but what I am doing is do vanilla that I can't believe I need to do something from the commandline.

[EDIT] Here is what happened when I added `Default.aspx` as a default document:
[image]

There are a few things to try, but all the instructions are a bit to vague for me to follow with confidence.  It also seems weird that I would have to run a commandline thing for something so common as getting IIS to use ASP.NET.

[EDIT] Here are the settings for the Default page:

[image]

[EDIT] Here is the configuration of the Application Pool:

[image]

Comment: Add default.aspx as default document and try again. IIS Manager makes it super easy to do so, and you have no need to use command line if you don't like.

Comment: Looks like a question of permissions more than anything. I haven't worked with a new server before so not sure what to check exactly. [MS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/942062/http-error-403-14-forbidden-error-when-you-open-an-iis-7-0-webpage)

Answer (score 2):

After going down all kinds of wrong paths I found this link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-using-aspnet-35-and-aspnet-45

which amounted to getting 4.6 checked on this wizard screen and pressing install.  It was confusing because this is under the development category and this is not a development machine.

[image]

Note: the hand added Default.aspx caused a conflict so I had to remove it from web.config by hand.

Comment: All I had was a static page that needed to be default. But the default settings in webconfig were ignored until asp.net 4.7 was added for Server 2019 IIS 10. Thanks for shining the light on this awkward relationship.

Answer (score -1):

you can see below link where you can find your answer.
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/francissvk/set-default-page-for-a-website-in-iis421/

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  This is precisely what I did between the time I posted the original question and what I put in the [EDIT].  Do you have any recommendations in light of the error message I received after I followed our instructions?  e.g.  The edit contains the results of following your instructions.  BTW:  welcome to stack overflow; some people will down vote link only answers.  Feel free to edit your answer to include a brief version of what is in the link to avoid that fate.